# Representing region with integrals, but with $ y $ variable instead of $ x $.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area, visualization

I'm having trouble getting this through my head. I have an exercise in which I'm told that $f(x) = \sqrt x $ and $ g(x) = 2-x $. Using definite integrals, I'm supposed to find the area of the region under the two functions.
This is fairly simple, it's not even the problem.

I've included an image of the graph and a link to the Desmos graph at the bottom of the page.

Before telling me to discover the area, they ask me to formulate it with integrals using the $x$ variable which I did, stating that the region could be represented by $ \int_0^1 f(x)dx + \int_1^2 g(x)dx$, and this answer is completely correct. The problem is that they then tell me to do the same using the $y$ variable, and the supposed correct answer is $\int_0^1 (2-y)dy - \int_0^1y^2dy$, and I cannot even visualize this in my mind. How can this be true? It checks out numerically, but how can this be correct?

*Edit: Also, since I'm having trouble visualizing the region in $y$-representation, is there a simple way to obtain it from the $x$-representation?

Resources:

- [Image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BTM1.png).
- [Desmos graph.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cidtwl2xac)

Comment: Imagine reflecting the whole picture across the diagonal line $y=x$.

Comment: Thank you, but even then, shouldn't the definite integral values still be from 0-1 and 1-2?

Comment: $\int_0^1 (2-y)dy$ is the area of the trapezoid with vertices $(0,0), (2,0), (1,1)$, and $(0,1)$; to get the area of the shaded region, subtract $\int_0^1 y^2 dy$

Comment: Got it! Re-reading your first comment helped since that was really all that it took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$\int_0^1 (2-y)dy$ is the area of the  red, blue, and purple areas;

to get the area you want, subtract the red area, which is $\int_0^1 y^2 dy$.

Comment: This was the simplest way to explain it, thank you so much. Practically speaking, I just had to look at it sideways. So if I'm, not mistaken $\int_0^1 y^2  dy$ is the red area, correct?

Comment: You are correct, @Hasake